# popViewControllerAnimated animation not working in iOS5

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, poptoviewcontroller

Trying to back to previous viewController, but animation in iOS5 not working.

```
- (IBAction)backToPreviousController
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: add NSLogs to make sure that 1. the method is actually called and 2. self.navigationController is not nil.

Comment: this works definitely. there is no problem with this method. problem will be somewhere else in your code

Comment: I'am returning to the previous viewController, but without animation. In the iOS4 works great,

Comment: Where are you calling `backToPreviousController`? Looks like it's from a button tap or something (due to the `IBAction`) but is it possible you're calling it from somewhere else which could have an effect. Also, do you see no animation at all and it just pops right to the previous view or do you see some animation?

Answer (score 2):

From the OP, [Davey Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925617/davey-jones)~

Problem solved by adding animation manually

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation]; 
transition.duration = 0.5; 
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]; 
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; 
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; 
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```